Why am I getting a "JC_CONTAINER_NOT_OPENED ERROR 145034" in GridDB when performing operations on a container?
I'm working with GridDB to manage a distributed database and recently encountered the following error while performing operations on a container:
145034 JC_CONTAINER_NOT_OPENED ERROR Status check of client request failed.
from griddb_python import GridStoreFactory, StoreFactory

def perform_griddb_operations():
    try:
        factory = StoreFactory.get_default()
        gridstore = factory.get_store({
            "host": "239.0.0.1",
            "port": 41999,
            "cluster_name": "defaultCluster",
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "admin"
        })

        # Attempt to get a container
        container = gridstore.get_container("containerName")
        if container is None:
            raise Exception("Container not found")

        # Perform some operations on the container
        row = container.get(1)
        print(f"Row retrieved: {row}")

        container.put(2, {"id": 2, "value": "value2"})
        print("Row inserted")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Operation failed: {e}")
        raise

if __name__ == "__main__":
    perform_griddb_operations()

I connect to the GridDB cluster and attempt to get a container named "containerName".
I then try to retrieve a row and insert a new row into this container.
Despite following the documentation, I frequently encounter the JC_CONTAINER_NOT_OPENED ERROR 145034. This error suggests that the container might not be properly opened or the operation might be performed incorrectly.
Here are some additional details about my setup:
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04
Python Version: 3.8
GridDB Version: 4.5
Cluster Size: 5 nodes
I'm looking for guidance on:
Common causes of the JC_CONTAINER_NOT_OPENED ERROR 145034.
Best practices for ensuring containers are correctly opened before performing operations.
Any additional logging or checks I should implement to diagnose this issue further.
Has anyone experienced similar issues with GridDB, or can anyone provide insights into what might be going wrong?
